# Linux find command with multiple command -exec using chown and chmod

Tags: linux, find, exec

The following command runs but the two `-exec` commands don't run - so the file gets moved but the permissions and file owner doesn't change.

`find ~/Downloads/ -name "2014-12-24*"
  -exec sudo mv {} ~/docs/ \;
  -exec sudo chown {} apache:apache \;
  -exec sudo chmod {} 400 \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are moving, say, `Downloads/2014-12-24-first` to `~/docs/2014-12-24-first`, and THEN trying to change the owner and permissions on `Downloads/2014-12-24-first`; which will not work, because you have already moved the file to `~/docs`.

Try re-ordering your `-exec`s so the `chmod`/`chown` are first, and the `mv` last.